# Nest Js build to Heroku is successful but routes not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, nestjs, prisma

So for tow days i struggle to deploy my first backend app to Heroku (i use nest.js with prisma), but i get all sort of errors. I've bring all to latest versions and now I struggle with only one error but I can't figure it out. As far I can tell the problem is in my package.json. Can someone take a look at this package.json file and tell me what I missed?

I think that i've tried all posible version from stackoverflow and other tutorials for `"start:prod"` script. I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Thank you so much in advance!

If you have any hint on what I should do to fix this it's much apreciate because i'm stuck at this.

This is my package.json

```
{
  
  "name": "dez-backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node":"18.x",
    "npm": "9.x"
  },
  "description": "Backend developed for edez mobile App",
  "author": "Draghici Adrian",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "postinstall": "npx prisma generate && npm run build",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/axios": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.3.9",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.3.9",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.3.9",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.997.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nestjs-s3": "^1.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.2.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.3.9",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.36",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  } 
}
```

And this are the logs from Heroku:

```
2023-03-04T10:39:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-03-0410:39:43.776332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "npm run start:prod*
2023-03-04T10:39:47.341244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
config
2023-03-04T10:39:46.879061+00:00 app [web. 1]: pm WARN config production Use
--omit=dev' instead.
2023-03-04T10:39:46.938577+00:00 app [web. 1]:
2023-03-04T10:39:46.938579+00:00 app [web. 1]: > dez-backend@0.0.1 start:prod
2023-03-04T10:39:46.938581+00:00 app [web. 1]: > node dist/main
2023-03-04T10:39:46.938581+00:00 app [web. 1]:
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029449+00:00 app [web. 1] : node: internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1078
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029452+00:00 app [web.1]: throw err;
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029452+00:00 app [web. 1]:
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029453+00:00 app [web. 1]:
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029453+00:00 app [web. 1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
2023-03-04710:39:47.029453+00:00 app (web. 1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node: internal/modules/cis/loader: 1075:15)
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029454+00:00 app [web. 1]: at Module._load (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader: 920:27)
2023-03-04710:39:47.029454+00:00 app[web. 1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node: internal/modules/run_mai n:81:12)
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029454+00:00 app [web. 1]: at node: internal/main/run_main_module: 23:47 {
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029455+00:00 app [web. 1]: code: 'MODULE NOT FOUND'
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029455+00:00 app [web. 1]: requireStack: []
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029455+00:00 app [web. 1]: }
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029470+00:00 app [web. 1]:
2023-03-04T10:39:47.029470+00:00 app [web. 1]: Node.is v18.14.2
2023-03-04T10:39:47.292073+00:00 heroku[web. 1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the problem:

Instead of :

```
"start:prod": "node dist/main",
```

I added :

```
"start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
```

And it worked. The main file was located in ../src/main.ts. So i need to add the correct path to it.